# What encoding is used for Ethereum addresses?

Tags: addresses, encoding

Is it [Base58Check](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Base58Check_encoding), which is used for Bitcoin addresses? Or something else?

Comment: Ethereum uses hexadecimal digits for it addresses, with optional checksum (https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/issues/55).